# How to determine the supremum and infimum of $a_n = \frac{(-2)^{n+1} + 3^{n}}{3^{n+1} + (-2)^n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I have successfully proven that $\lim(a_n) = \frac{1}{3}$ by shortening the fraction by $3^{n+1}$ and determining the limit of the resulting term. From this, I conclude that $a_n$ is bounded.

Now I want to find the infimum and supremum of this sequence. Judging the first few elements, I suspect that they are $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{43}{73}$ respectively. However, I can't find a way to prove it. What approach would you take here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if the sequence has a minimum element, it must necessarily be its infimum; similar for a maximum element.

Now the sequence has both; calculating the first $20$ elements highly indicates that $a_1 = 1$ is maximal and $a_2 = \frac{1}{31}$ is minimal. It remains to prove this fact.

Divide the sequence in the elements with odd index $O_n$ and even index $E_n$. This is to get rid of the minus sign under the exponent; a common tactic with these kind of problems. Prove that $O_n$ is decreasing and greater than $\frac{1}{3}$, while $E_n$ is increasing and smaller than $\frac{1}{3}$. The maximality/minimality of $1$ and $\frac{1}{31}$ follow.

Comment: Even using that approach, the task remains difficult to me. Starting with the sequence $O_n$, I hoped to be able to show that the nominator decreases while the denominator increases, thus decreasing $O_{n+1}$ as a whole. However, both terms are growing. Then, I attempted a proof by induction. In that case, I have to show $\frac{ 2^{n+1} + 3^n }{ 3^{n+1} - 2^n } > \frac{ 4 \cdot 2^{n+1} + 9 \cdot 3^n }{ 9 \cdot 3^{n+1} - 4 \cdot 2^n }$ (note I increased $n$ by 2 in the induction step). This seems very difficult to relate to the induction condition as well. What else can I try?

Comment: You don't need to use induction; simply prove the inequality for arbitrary n. Multiply by the product of the denominators on both sides; a lot of common terms disappear

Answer (score 3):

$a_n=\frac{7}{3+x}-2$ where $x=(-\frac{2}{3})^{n}$.

$-\frac{2}{3}\le x\le\frac{4}{9}$, if $n=0$ is not included.

Therefore  $\frac{7}{3}\le 3+x\le \frac{31}{9}$

and $\frac{1}{31}\le a_n\le 1$.